# xp_cmdshell keeps running in the background

Tags: sql-server

A query `xp_cmdshell` has been running in the background for quite sometime now (a few days!). How do I get rid of it? I may have run it while I was testing some queries. How do I kill this query?

I tried

```
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

But it is still running in the background. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: on the Windows Server where SQL Server is, run task manager look for command prompt task and kill it

Comment: @Squirrel Can't I kill the process with some query? I don't have the admin privileges to stop the task in the Server.

Comment: Unfortunately the xp_cmdshell kicks of a process that runs and then waits for a response back.  Until the command finishes the SQL Server will continue to wait.  There is only three ways to fix it: 1) Kill the task with task manager, 2) Reboot the server 3) Restart the SQL server service.  Keep in mind that depending on the task #2 and #3 may cause the server to stall while waiting for the SQL service to stop.  That being said, I would find someone who IS an admin on the box and tell them to kill it.